# add AWS RUM to a site built with deno lume

Tags: deno, rum, lume

i have a static site built with lume, with AWS RUM snippet added to the `<HEAD>` section, content does not render.

---

i tried adding the following line to `_data.yml` :

```
extra_head: 
  - <script async src="https://source-to/rum.js" />
```

while the file `rum.js` is the downloaded HTML snippets from AWS RUM, with the `<SCRIPT>` tags removed. ( i.e. not the one which requires npm package installations )

when i do this, it can be deployed to deno deploy, but the page will load forever that cannot render any content at all.

browser console has not shown any errors.

tried brave browser with shields down, and on Edge, got the same behaviors.

am i missing anything ? anybody had succeed doing so ?